# Whitespace in name of list box- html

Tags: php, html

I have an html file with code for a form

```
<select name="listbox" size="3">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

I am using the values in a php script. If I rename 'listbox' to 'list box' it does not work in any browser.
I take it it's because of the white space, right? Are white spaces in names not allowed in html? 
Thank you for any help.

Comment: @Raidenace: no, it shouldn't. HTML attribute-values are white-space delimited, a name of `list box` would be *two* names (which is invalid).

Answer (score 4):

Read the specification at http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

> **ID** and **NAME** tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: Thank you. I've just started html etc and hadn't come across this before. But why it displays the list box correctly on the browser? It does not take the name into account when displaying?

Comment: nope, name does not affect the visual representation so it matter not if it even has one..

Comment: This is incorrect! Browsers have no problem whatsoever parsing form data with attributes having spaces in their names or they starting with digits. This seems to be a PHP issue only.

Comment: @Ravi, the browser might be able to parse it but it still is invalid HTML. PHP is just adhering to the standard and expects names without spaces..

Comment: To be even more precise you could make it work, but it is really just asking for trouble.. Read http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php It states "***Dots and spaces in variable names are converted to underscores. For example `<input name="a.b" />` becomes `$_REQUEST["a_b"]`.***"

Answer (score 0):

Try this HTML. Both Mozilla Firefox and IE are fine with it!

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Name Attribute with Spaces</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get"> <!-- no "action", form will post to self -->
 <table>
   <thead><b>Please provide login details</b></thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Username:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="user name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="pass word" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>List Box:</td>
        <td>
            <select name="123 list box" size="3">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The reason HTML doesn't have any problems with spaces is ***URL Encoding***. If you test the above form you'll find the browsers automatically encode special characters and hence a space " " gets converted to a "+" (or, sometimes "%20").

`test.html?user+name=ravi&pass+word=canuseeme&123+list+box=2`

The reason why PHP seems to run into trouble here (from what I vaguely remember) is that it tries to expose request parameters as easily accessible variables to the PHP programmer. And variable names in any language do not contain spaces or start with numbers.

*Edit:* In fact, if you make ***multiple selections*** true for your select box (just add *multiple* attribute in *select*) the name needs to end in `"[]"` to give PHP a hint that it needs to arrange for an Array variable!